# Lipschitz Homeomorphisms Between Spheres of N-dimensional Spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces

Let $B_p^N$ be the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^N$ under the $\ell_p^N$ norm.

**Question:** Let $C_N$ be the infimum of all $C$     for which there is a homeomorphism $f_N$ from $B_\infty^N$ onto $B_2^N$ so that the Lipschitz constant of $f_N$  is  $C$.  Is $C_N$ bounded as $N\to \infty$?

Notice that the $\ell_\infty^N$ norm  is $2$-equivalent to the $\ell_p^N$ norm with $p = \log_2 N$, and the Mazur map from $B_p^N$ to $B_2^N$ has Lipschitz constant about $p$, so $C_N$ grows no faster than $\log N$.

(The Mazur map from $\ell_p$ to $\ell_2$ is defined for unit vectors to be $x\mapsto |x|^{p/2}\rm{sign}\  x$ and extended to be positively homogeneous on $\ell_p$.)

Comment: Lovely question! (BTW, what is 2-equivalent?)

Comment: Just to be sure: the Lipschitz constant $C$ refers to the $\ell^N_\infty$ distance on the domain and $\ell^N_2$ distance on the co-domain of $f_N$, right?

Comment: $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_p \le 2 \|x\|_\infty$ for all $x$, Gil.

Right, Pietro.

Comment: is it clear that if one of those balls may be covered by balls of radii $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n$, then the other may be covered by balls of radii $Cr_1,\dots,Cr_n$ for some universal $C$? I.e. that both conditions are equivalent (up to constant) to some $\sum r_i^n=O(1)$?

Comment: @Fedor Petrov. $C=3$ works.  Assume $1\ge r_1\ge r_2 \ge...$. Choose non overlapping balls $B_1,...,B_n$ inside the 2nd unit ball $B$, $B_i$ of radius $r_i$, until impossible.  If always possible, volumetric considerations show that the union of these balls contains all but a measure zero set of $B$ and hence any $C>1$ works, so assume the process stops at $k$.  Blow up each $B_1,...,B_{k-1}$ by a factor  of $3$ and let $D$ be the union of these inflated balls and $E$ the union of $B_1,...,B_{k-1}$. If $D$ does not contain $B$, there is a point $x$ in $B$ whose distance to $E$ is $\ge 2r_k$,

Comment: hence there is a point $y$ in $B$ whose distance both to $E$ and to the boundary of $B$ is at least $r_k$.

Comment: I was thinking something similar. A large $N$-dimensional cube is very efficiently covered by unit cubes, and the existence of such homeomorphism $f_N$ tells something about how efficiently an $N$ dimensional Euclidean ball of radius $R>>1$ can be covered by unit balls. Though I wasn't able to find if there are around known results on the "ball covering problem" that can give a lower bound on the $C_N$.

Comment: @Pietro: a standard volume comparison argument shows that in any $N$-dimensional normed space, the ball of radius $R\ge 1$ can be covered by $(3R)^N$ unit balls.  This seems to give only a constant lower bound on the $C_N$.

Comment: By the way, is the same question for the homeo with uniformly bounded bi-Lipschitz (not just Lipschitz) constant obvious? I do not see any simple argument (nor hard one, too).

Comment: @Fedor Petrov:  Differentiate to get a linear isomorphism to see that the bi-Lipschitz equivalence constant is no smaller than the isomorphism constant, which is $n^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry for asking stupid questions, but does not the same argument solve the initial problem? I mean, if the linear operator from $\ell_{\infty}^n$ to $\ell_2^n$ has norm at most $C$, does not it decrease the Haussdorf measure too much?  

Comment: The derivative of the supposed Lipschitz map will have norm at most $C$, but the norm of its inverse (at any point where the derivative   exists) will have norm at least $C^{-1}N^{1/2}$.  In the problem I mentioned, there is no control of the Lipschitz constant of the inverse of $f$ (which must be at least $C^{-1}N^{1/2}$ if the inverse is Lipschitz, by the differentiation argument I mentioned). 

Comment: ah, sorry, this approach fails, since the unit cube, inscribed in a Euclidean ball, has a volume $C^N$-comparable to that of the unit ball.